# For loop blank condition

Tags: java

The condition in the for loop is left blank and the code compiles and runs.

```
 for(int i=0; ; i++)
    System.out.print(i);  //this code does not execute
 //code after this does not execute
```

But, I don't understand how and **why** this is possible.

Comment: Can you provide also the context around the for loop? Does it print anything if you add `System.out.print("test")` a line before the for loop?

Comment: Are you sure that portion is executed? It should run forever...

Comment: possible duplicate of [For loop with no parameters in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6051869/for-loop-with-no-parameters-in-java)

Comment: And one more question: Will it run if you change it to `System.out.println(i);` ? I think it may be using some buffer and not actually print it till EOL, but I'm not 100% sure about it.

Comment: System.out.print should also work println will not change anything

Comment: Please put the someWord before the for loop, not after it. Here it is unreachable because it is after the infinite loop, which is never left, if you need to add it to the for loop, you should put both the lines in curly brackets.

Comment: I have a doubt. In Java, unreachable code is an error, so how does this code compiles?

Answer (score 3):

Just change below line, although its not an issue.

```
System.out.print(i);  //this code does not seems execute by checking o/p on console but in reals it works as well.
```

To

```
System.out.println(i);  //this code works and you will be able to see o/p on console.
```

OR

```
System.out.print(i+" "); // this will show you some momentary action on Eclipse console.
```

It seems to me as some Eclipse IDE console printing issue. With the first version as you mentioned in your question, I can't see any output. As `print()` keeps on printing on the same line may be its not visible to us.

However, if you run your code in Debug mode and place a breakpoint on the above line. Breakpoint will hit and you can see the output being printed as well.

But for the second version, I can see it printing all number starting from 0,1...

This is a [similar discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10948983/system-out-print-doesnt-send-any-output-to-eclipse-console-why) as shared by @PakkuDon

Comment: This looks right to me. I reckon [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10948983/system-out-print-doesnt-send-any-output-to-eclipse-console-why) might be worth adding to your post as well.

Answer (score 2):

If it prints nothing, it means you're not reaching this for loop at all.
If you're reaching it, it should print all numbers from 0 going up.
This is an endless loop printing 0, 1, 2, ...
Your problem is elsewhere (probably before the for loop).

Comment: Just a clarification: the initial question was why this loop does not print anything.

Answer (score 2):

After testing this in netbeans it goes like this:

While application is running:
no output

When application is stopped:
all the numbers are outputted in the console.

So it does work, look at references from other answers to know WHY it works.

Answer (score 2):

A For loop construct have three things `Initialization`,`Condition` and `Increment/Decrements` these are not mandatory fields. Java will always execute the code and won't show an error because we not breaking any syntax rule.

In here `for(i=0;;i++) System.out.println(i)` will still be executed and result into infinite loop because Condition are always treated as optional part so rest other two.

Therefore, we wont be able to reach code after `System.out.println(i)`statement as we are stuck in an infinite loop.